# chef data bag search returns 0 items, even though items are present

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife, databags

when we run the below command from Knife workstation,

knife search data_bag_name id:data_bag_item_id 
its returning 0 items,even though items are present in Chef server. If we do knife data bag show data_bag_name data_bag_item_id its showing the data bag item.

This is not working in recipe as well. What could be the issue?

Comment: Hi, I've checked the command " knife search data_bag_name 'id:data_bag_item_id' " and it works for me. Are you sure that you type the correct data_bag_name and the correct data_bag_item_id?

Comment: Try launching `chef-server-ctl reindex`on your server, sometimes the solr index crash.

Comment: This problem got resolved after running chef-server-ctl reindex on chef server. Thanks @Tensibai

Answer (score 0):

Run  `chef-server-ctl reindex` in Chef server solves the issue.